# Creating new instance of subquery with sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I have the following columns among three tables

**Movie**

```
mID | title | year | director
```

**Reviewer**

```
rID | name
```

**Rating**

```
rID | mID | stars | ratingDate
```

The instructions that I have been given are:

"For all cases where the same reviewer rated the same movie twice and gave it a higher rating the second time, return the reviewer's name and the title of the movie"

The way I have approached this so far is I have done a three way merge of all the tables to capture all the needed information. What I wanted to do next is create an new instance of this three way merge and find where reviewer and movie are equal and where rating is higher. This is what I have so far

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *
FROM Movie Mov
INNER JOIN Rating Rat
   ON Mov.mID = Rat.mID
INNER JOIN Reviewer REv
   ON Rev.rID = Rat.rID) A, A table;
WHERE ...
```

The problem is that I am not able to create a new instance of A. Here I am attempting to do this here `A table`.

If anyone has any other suggestions on how to better approach this problem that is more clear please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with a problem like this the first task is to find the rows you want. I would do that with a query like this:

```
select *
from Rating as r1
where exists (
   select 1
  from rating as r2
  where r1.rid = r2.rid
  and   r1.mid = r2.mid 
  and   r1.stars < r2.stars
  and   r1.ratingDate < r2.ratingDate
  )
```

Then add the parts you want to fetch (much as you were doing):

```
select title, name
from Rating as r1
inner join Movie as m on m.mid = r1.mid
inner join Reviewer as z on z.rid = r1.rid
where exists (
   select 1
  from rating as r2
  where r1.rid = r2.rid
  and   r1.mid = r2.mid 
  and   r1.stars < r2.stars
  and   r1.ratingDate < r2.ratingDate
  )
```

Here is a fiddle with test data showing it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/5f0f8/3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT v.Name AS Reviewer, m.Name AS Movide
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A.rID, A.mID
   FROM Rating A INNER JOIN Rating B
   ON A.rID = B.rID AND A.mID = B. mID 
   WHERE A.ratingDate > B.ratingDate
   AND A.starts > B.starts
 ) s
JOIN Reviewer v ON v.rID =s.rID
JOIN Movie m ON m.mID = s.mID
```

I didn't test on Sqlite, however.